# img object width and height ignored when drawing on canvas

Tags: image, canvas, height, width

I'm changing width and height of an image object before drawing on canvas:

```
        earth.onload = function () {
            this.width = 50;
            this.height = 50;
        }
        earth.src = 'images/earth-transparent.png';

        // and later on

        function drawPlanet(xCenter, yCenter, radius, speed, img) {
            var ms = time.getSeconds() * 1000 + time.getMilliseconds();
            var angle = ((2 * Math.PI) / (speed * 1000) * ms);
            var xDelta = radius * Math.sin(angle);
            var yDelta = radius * Math.cos(angle);
            var x = xCenter + xDelta;
            var y = yCenter + yDelta;
            ctx.drawImage(img, x - img.width / 2, y - img.height / 2, img.width, img.height);
        }
        var time = new Date();
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,153,255,0.4)';
        ctx.save();
        drawPlanet(300, 300, 200, 6, earth);
```

(drawPlanet is called in the callback of a setInterval, thus the load event of the image has fired) Unfortunately the size of the image being drawn is the original one. When I output width and height in the debugger their value is 50. Why is this?

Comment: yes, `drawImage` uses the `naturalWidth` and `naturalHeight` values. But you can achieve easily your goal with the 4th and 5th parameters of `drawImage(img, x,y,width,height)`

Comment: I see, didn't expect this. 4th and 5th parameter works fine, thank you. However I assume that it's bad from the aspect of performance as the image has to be resized every time the function is called. As I mentioned it is called periodically at an interval of 20 ms.

Comment: Not really, drawImage is fast even with resize and cropping options. You should be fine if you don't call it more than 5K times per frame. If you really want to call only the 3 params version in your loop, you can always draw the resized image on an offscreen canvas and draw this offscreen canvas in the loop. But anyway, don't use a setInterval for your animation, use an requestAnimationFrame loop instead.

Comment: Thanks for these additional hints. Using an offscreen canvas is a fine idea. I did this in a different script some time ago but it didn't come to my mind now. But maybe you are right and it's not really necessary. Will consider switching to requestAnimationFrame .